# Getting total download bandwidth served from file size and total download count

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a `files` table with these attributes:

```
f_id, s_id, u_id, name, size, downloads, uploaded
```

I want my user account page to show the total bandwidth served by the users uploads. To do this, I need to take the size of each of the users upload and then * it by the downloads, and then add up all the results.

Originally I was getting the users total filesizes and then * by their total downloads, but obviously that's not accurate. Here's an example of my query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(downloads)
        AS downloads
        FROM `files`
        WHERE u_id = (SELECT u_id FROM `users` WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1)
        LIMIT 1';
```

How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(size*downloads) AS bandwidth
FROM files f
   JOIN users u
      ON f.u_id = u.u_id
WHERE u.username = ?
GROUP BY u.u_id
```

this will provide you a number which represents the bandwidth generated by the user's uploads